# Recycle bin and External HDD

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, recycle-bin

When I plug in my Seagate external hard disk, it has a folder named $RECYCLE.BIN which is empty. Its been fine upto now.

Now when i delete a folder from my Desktop of my PC, the folder goes into the recycle bin of my PC which is also good according to the logic. But now the problem arrises. The deleted folder also appears into the $RECYCLE.BIN folder of the Seagate external hard disk drive. This is shown in the below pics.

[image: Recycle bin folder of my PC has the deleted folder]

[image: $RECYCLE.BIN folder of Seagate external hard disk has the deleted pic]

My question is why does this pic goes into the $RECYCLE.BIN folder of the Seagate external hard disk .I mean the folder should have ONLY went into the recycle bin folder of PC.

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Can you plug in the hard disk into another computer and check if the files are there? The file may not actually be on the external hard disk.

Comment: More information: https://forums.techguy.org/threads/duplicate-recycle-bins.1015008/

Comment: I checked it...it's not there on extrnal HDD when its is connected to another computer....But why is the issue??why is it  happening  this way??

Comment: Quoting from the link above: `the one on the "J" drive is just a link to the real one on the "C" drive`, assuming the information is correct.

Comment: what i understood from the link u provided is that.....$RECYCLE.BIN folder on external HDD is the instance of recycle bin ....that means in actual we have the recycle bin only on our PC...am i correct??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Recycle Bin view is global for the entire system including viewing the Recycle Bin on any fixed drive even your external Seagate which is likely being mounted as fixed per the drives firmware.

If Windows mounts the drive as Fixed instead of External, then your Recycle Bin behavior is to be expected.

Using Disk Manager (diskmgmt.msc), if your USB connected Seagate is listed as Fixed, then the drives firmware is detected as fixed by design thus extending  some additional features normally reserved for fixed drives versus limitations of USB jump drives.

Features such as easy NTFS formatting, encrypting file system, the Recycle Bin and others.